# sorting only what's in parentheses in a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
s = "Kadu (b, a), Dadu, Adu (y, i)"
```

I need this string to be sorted as follows:

`Adu (i, y), Dadu, Kadu (a, b)`

Extra explanation for those who have one more minute: As a translator, I sometimes have to translate alphabetically sorted, comma-delimited lists in which some of the items have sub-lists in parentheses, also alphabetically sorted. After the translation, the alphabetical order changes, so I have to resort everything using primitive tools like Word. I'm trying to write myself some code that can help me automatise this. I'm very new to coding, I can basically only do patchwork using what I find around here but I'm learning.

Thanks to some Regex code I used in Python, I was able to split the string in the right way, sort it and then rejoin the list. 
As of now I am able to get this:

`Adu (y, i), Dadu, Kadu (b, a)`

As you see, the main list is nicely sorted but what's inside parentheses remains untouched.

```
import re
s = "Kadu (b, a), Dadu, Adu (y, i)"
unsorted = re.split(r',\s*(?![^()]*\))', s)
unsorted.sort()
result = ", "
result = result.join(unsorted)
print(result)
```

Now I guess I need to write some Regex code that treats only what's in parentheses. I haven't been able to find a piece of code I can adapt for this. Does anyone know how I should do it?

Comment: How do you split `s` to `unsorted` list, please add that code too

Comment: Yes, that splitting method can be used to sort the items inside parentheses. Please edit the question

Comment: unsorted = re.split(r',\s*(?![^()]*\))', s) I added it in the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a callback function to find the parts within `(...)` and replace it with a sorted version of itself.

```
>>> ', '.join(sorted(re.sub("(?<=\().+(?=\))", lambda m: ', '.join(sorted(m .group().split(', '))), x) for x in re.split(r',\s*(?![^()]*\))', s))) 
'Adu (i, y), Dadu, Kadu (a, b)'
```